# Error The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type number

Tags: android, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I'm getting this error while trying to run an Alloy app using Appcelerator Studio on MacOS.

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit 
 value was 1
 2018-06-17T04:43:42.736Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
 The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type number
 2018-06-17T04:43:42.737Z | ERROR  | The "path" argument must be of type 
 string. Received type number
 2018-06-17T04:43:42.737Z | TRACE  | TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: 
 The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type number


 path must be a string. Received 26
 2018-06-17T05:05:09.071Z | ERROR  | Path must be a string. Received 26
 2018-06-17T05:05:09.071Z | TRACE  | TypeError: Path must be a string. 
 Received 26
```

Comment: Is it just a new project without any modifications? Are you trying to run iOS or Android?

Comment: No its not a new project, i'm using Android.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed node-v8.9.4 and used the following commands and it's working now:

```
 sudo rm -rf ~/.appcelerator
 sudo rm -rf ~/.titanium
 sudo npm uninstall -g titanium
 sudo npm uninstall -g appcelerator
 sudo npm install -g appcelerator
 appc use latest
 appc setup
```